# Rendering MeV/c² with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, units

I'm trying to render the unit MeV/c² using `siunitx`.

In the preamble I have defined `\DeclareSIUnit\eVperc{\eV\per\clight}` but `\(m = \SI{5}{\mega\eVperc\squared}\)` gives me "*m* = 5 MeVc₀⁻²" which is not what I want.

I have tried just about every combination of `per-mode`, `per-symbol` and `sticky-per` that I can think of, but nothing gives me what I want. I want to continue using indices for all the other units.

This is the only place that I am using `\clight` so a simple hack for getting rid of the subscript zero would be fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The subscript zero is part of the `\clight` unit, so you'll need to redefine that. Below I copied the definition of `\clight` from `siunitx.sty` and removed the subscript.

[image: screenshot of output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\eVperc{\eV\per\clight}
\DeclareSIUnit\clight{\text{\ensuremath{c}}}
\begin{document}
\(m = \SI[per-mode=symbol]{5}{\mega\eVperc\squared}\)
\end{document}
```